# Access a variable after several references

Tags: c#, design-patterns, unity3d, reference

I have a **team lead** that used to write references in a single script then access it in every script. Like for accessing a variable he has to write code in this way `staticRef.scpRefGui.CLDropDown_Ref.Dropdown_ref.value`

And sometime I see this kind of function calling  `staticRef.scpRefGui.CQAScrollViewPOI_Ref.ShowExcelObjsInScrollView(username,WS_EnumClass.POIYaInfo.POI, list);`

Here is another example, this code is getting a key from references file:

```
 public void testDict() {
        if (scpRef.AutoQADict_Ref.DictQA.ContainsKey(SheetNameDict))
        {
            if (scpRef.AutoQADict_Ref.DictQA[SheetNameDict].ContainsKey(UsernameDict))
            {
                if (scpRef.AutoQADict_Ref.DictQA[SheetNameDict][UsernameDict].ContainsKey(ObjName)) {
                    Debug.Log("dict: " + scpRef.AutoQADict_Ref.DictQA[SheetNameDict][UsernameDict][ObjName]);
                }
                else { 
                        Debug.Log("ObjName: " + ObjName + " Not Found");

                    }
            }
            else {
                Debug.Log("UsernameDict: " + UsernameDict + " Not Found");
            }
        }
        else {
            Debug.Log("SheetNameDict Key: " + SheetNameDict + " Not Found");
        }
    }
```

I have **strong disagreement** of this way of coding. As it is unclear, contains several references, against SOLID, hard to debug etc (maybe I am wrong thats why i posted here).  Please help me that this is a valid approach? You(this site) have reviewed so many codes! Seriously bad code design kills you, and i am killing myself after seeing/updating this kind of code.

Comment: Everything about that code is bad. It doesn't follow the usual naming standards for one, it uses words like "ref" and "static" and "dict" in their names, and it doesn't use [`TryGetValue()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue). And using nested dictionaries -- why not write proper classes with properties etc.? Where did this team lead even pick up these spectacularly bad habits?

Comment: I guess self coined!